# Non-Negligible function arithmetics

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, cryptography

Following the [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578586/negligible-function-arithmetics?noredirect=1#comment1223103_578586): If a function is known to be `non-neligible` by [this definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negligible_function), (for example $q(x)=1/x$, is it true (provable) that $poly(x)*q(x)$ (for any positive polynomial function) is also a `non-negligible` function?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, trivially.  If $poly(x)$ is a positive polynomial, then $poly(x) * q(x) > q(x)$ for all $x$.  Since $q(x)$ is `non-negligible`, $poly(x) * q(x)$ is also `non-negligible`.